# Returning values from Javascript function calll

Tags: javascript

This is really a question around Javascript scope and functions so I apologise as I'm a newbie to JS!!

I have a snippet of javascript, that connects creates a HTTPClient connection to a REST service from Vertx - this all works fine no issues here.

My problem is that I need access to the "status" and "data" returned from the "client.request" outside of this call

```
// Create the HTTP Client
var client = vertx.createHttpClient().host(host).port(ssl_port).ssl(true);


var request = client.request("POST", "/api/en/v1.0/authentication/token/new" + "?login_id=" + login_id + "&api_key=" + api_key, function(resp) {

    //console.log("Got a response: " + resp.statusCode());
    resp.bodyHandler(function(body) {
        // Parse the JSON string into a new object.
        var response = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log("status : " + response.status);
        console.log("data : " + response.data);
    })
});


request.end();
```

So in code down here I'd like to use/access "status" and "data". In another language I'd just return them as an object up the call stack.

Comment: Detailed explanation about javascript scopes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope

Comment: @Matt: I was considering changing the title (and answer) to be more generic, targeting asynchronous function calls in general.

Comment: @FelixKling make it happen `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Store them in a variable outside the of function and you have access to it. If you need to know when the information is available, define a callback function or take a look at javascript custom events.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing in javascript as well. Refer this [document](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp).

You can create a class:

```
function httpResponse(status,data) {
this.status=status;
this.data=data;
}
```

Set values like:

```
var myStatus = new httpResponse(response.status, response.data);
```

Add return statement:

```
return myStatus;
```

In your calling code you can access this data as:

```
var status = myStatus.status;
```

Answer (score -1):

Define a global variable outside the function.

```
var myVariable1_status;
var myVariable1_data;
```

Then assign the status and data-value to the variables inside the function.

```
function(){
    myVariable1_status = status;
    myVariable1_data = data;
}
```

Comment: The assignment nested in another function and declaring the variables with "var" will hide the globals.

Comment: Yes true. Copy-paste mistake... now edited..